# Templates and Inheritance: "cannot convert" in initialization

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am not able to solve the error in c++ template inheritance related code.

```
template <class row>

struct tableBase
{
    typedef row pkeytype;   

    int k;
};


template <typename row>
struct table:tableBase<typename row::pkeytype>
{
    row r;
};


 struct astruct {

    typedef int pkeytype;   
    char y;
};



table<astruct> atable;

tableBase<astruct>  * u=&atable;
```

error: cannot convert `table<astruct>*` to `tableBase<astruct>*` in initialization

Comment: `table<astruct>*` is convertable to `tableBase<int>*` though.

Comment: @MooingDuck: structs have public inheritance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the parent of `table<astruct>` is `tableBase<int>` NOT `tableBase<astruct>` which are two totally unrelated types.

Unfortunately since I can't conjecture what you're attempting to accomplish here I can't offer any suggested solutions.

Comment: Actually I was trying to simulate sqltable using stl and stuck in between. Something like this: `table3<Player,tableReferedBy<Score> > players;
 table2<Score,tableForiegn<Player > > scores(players);`

Comment: @MarkB What would best be done here? Maybe do a `reinterpret_cast<>()` on `atable`?

Comment: @Nik-Lz I can safely say `reinterpret_cast` is not the correct solution to the underlying problem here. Unfortunately the OP never updated the question with the real problem they were trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
tableBase<astruct>  * u=&atable;
```

to

```
tableBase<astruct::pkeytype>  * u=&atable;
```

(Note that tableBase's template parameter as defined in your code is initialized with the key type).

*Edit:*

I should state this will make your code compile. Making it work is a different matter ;P

Answer (score 0):

The types are not the same

```
table<astruct> atable; // This inherits from tableBase<astruct::pkeytype>


// The template type is astruct not astruct::pkeytype
tableBase<astruct>  * u=&atable;
```